# Show older or newer history items with the history command in zsh

Tags: zsh, command-history

I typed in the history command and it showed me the last 10 commands executed by me. Now I wanted to see the last 20 commands executed by me so (after reading the documentation):

> An argument of n lists only the last n lines.

I typed in `history 20`. This showed me all the commands starting from command number 20 to the current command which was somewhere around 2000. So I tried 
`history -20`
and this works. It shows me the last 20 commands. But this is not what is said in the documentation.

Also `history -d [offset]` is supposed to delete the command on that offset. Even that does not work in my zsh.

This is straight out of my zsh shell : 
[image]

Comment: "An argument of n lists only the last n lines" is in the documentation for bash. Zsh does things differently. http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands

Comment: On Linux, the `man builtins` command will show the **BASH BUILTIN COMMANDS** page, regardless of what shell you're using. Try `man zshbuiltins` or the web page in my previous comment to see the correct documentation.

Answer (score 8):

In zsh, `history` is an alias for `fc -l 1`, so when you do `history -20` it get replaced by `fc -l 1 -20` which just won't work, so instead use `fc` directly:

```
➜  ~  fc -l -20
10095  grep -R PAPER /usr/lib/locale/
10096  man locale
10097  man 7 locale
10098  mc
10099  history
10100  history --help
10101  run-help history
10102  history 20
10103  history 1 20
10104  history -l 20
10105  fc
10106  history -l 20
10107  type history
10108  fc -l ..20
10109  fc -l -20
10110  history -l -20
10111  history -20
10112  fc -l -20
10113  type history
10114  fc -l 1 -20
```

and you'll be fine.

Comment: You dint' understand my question. I know that history -20 (or fc -l -20) works. I want to know why history 20 (or fc -l 20) does not work ? It should work as per the documentation.

Comment: @user590849 `run-help history` doesn't say anything about that. Where did you find this documentation?

Comment: @Braiam: `history` ~~ `fc -l`, why `fc -l 1`?

Comment: @user590849, you're reading `bash` documentation, not `zsh` documentation.

Comment: Add the following to your .zshrc: `function lhistory() { fc -l -$1}` and use it like to show the last (for example) 10 commands: `lhistory 10`

Comment: in zsh, `history` is the same as `fc -l` (from `man zshbuiltins`), where do you get that info that `history` is `fc -l 1`?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to know, in `zsh`, `history` meaning `fc -l`.

Then read [man zshbuiltins](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands), section about `fc` command:

> Select a range of commands from **first to last** from the history list.
>   **The arguments first and last may be specified as a number or as a
>   string. A negative number is used as an offset to the current history
>   event number**. A string specifies the most recent event beginning with
>   the given string. All substitutions old=new, if any, are then
>   performed on the commands.
>
> ...
>
> If first is not specified, it will be set to -1 (the most recent
>   event), or to -16 if the -l flag is given. **If last is not specified,
>   it will be set to first, or to -1 if the -l flag is given**.

As the doc said, if negative number is used, it's an offset to the current history. So `history -20` list command from current to 20 command before.

If you provide a number `history 20`, `zsh` thinks it's `first to last` form. In this case, `first` is set to 20, but `last` is omitted. So `last` is set to `-1` because `fc -l` is used.

Comment: man zshbuiltins is huge and overwhelming for someone that just needs to get along with 'fc' instead of the old and remembered 'history'. Is there a way to ask  man zshbuiltins to only emit the lines about 'fc'???? something like  "man zshbuiltins fc" (which I tried and doesn't work)