# How do I alias history 20 to work the same way in zshell vs. bash?

Tags: bash, zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

Seems like `history [number]` is backward in zshell because it's using `fc`. How do I get `history [number]` to behave like it does in bash?

```
➜  exec bash
bash-3.2$ history 3
   35  history 5
   36  exit
   37  history 3
bash-3.2$ 

➜ history 3
    1  pwd
    2  ..
    3  mv work Documents

➜ history
   3133  history 5
   3134  exec bash
   3135  history
   3136  history 3
   3137  history -3
   3138  history 20
```

So in bash it behaves like I'd expect: last 3 commands. But in zshell it's backwards: the first 3 history commands. This is annoying and I'd like to fix it.

Closest I've got so far:

```
function history {
  fc -l -$1
}
```

But that still produces history starting at 1 instead of the last entry.

Related: [Show older or newer history items with the history command in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149125/show-older-or-newer-history-items-with-the-history-command-in-zsh)

Comment: I don't use `zsh`, but..  `alias history='history | tail -n${1-10}'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't as difficult as I thought it would be. Added this to my `~/.profile`

```
# zshell aliases history to "fc -l"

# quick version
alias h="fc -l -50"     # last 50

# history searching
function hg {
  echo "Searching for '$1'..."
  fc -l 0 | grep "$1"
}
```

Related and helpful: [Show older or newer history items with the history command in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149125/show-older-or-newer-history-items-with-the-history-command-in-zsh)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `bash` has it backwards, so if you flip the sign on the number...

```
$ PS1='%% ' zsh -f
% echo blah
blah
% echo de
de
% echo blah
blah
% history() { num=$(( -1 * $1 )); builtin history $num }
% history 3
    2  echo de
    3  echo blah
    4  history() { num=$(( -1 * $1 )); builtin history $num }
%
```

Comment: Uhh: `history 3 | wc -l `    -->  `3176`; that's what I get when I run your first 2 lines.

Comment: Probably oh-my-zsh bringing the usual derp. What happens under `zsh -f` with some history added?